# Replacing three words with one word without the replace function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to make a program where we replace any two/three words (in a string) of our choosing (e.g. replace "AWAY FROM KEYBOARD" with "AFK") without using replace, find, translate, or encode. I'm not sure exactly how this would be done. I've managed to be able to do this by replacing one word and making it shorter (I'm not allowed to post it) (i.e. changing "Hello" to "Hi"), but I can't seem to figure this one out. I've looked at similar questions but none really helped me without using stuff I'm not allowed to use or they had a different purpose.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please share your existing code? This is not only so that users can see what you've tried already, but also so that we know what level of explanation is required in responses. Also, have a read through *[mcve]*.

Comment: Hello, I've ended up deleting my code by fixing it, so I don't think I can anymore. Is that fine?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
user_in = input() # User inputs HELLO
s = "AWAY FROM KEYBOARD {}".format(user_in)
s = "{} {}".format(''.join([x[0] for x in s.split() if x != user_in]), user_in)
print(s)
# AFK HELLO
```

Comment: The string can sometimes have more than just "AWAY FROM KEYBOARD", for example, it can have "AWAY FROM KEYBOARD HELLO". When its like that, we just remove "AWAY FROM KEYBOARD" with "AFK" but we keep "HELLO", so it would be "AFK HELLO". Would it be possible to keep "HELLO" or anything else the user inputs?

Comment: Ah yes, that works. I'll test it out further for my other requirements, thanks :)

Comment: Unless you tell us clearly the inputs and the corresponding outputs, no one can manage to solve your issue. Why not edit your question based on what you need in a good formatted way so there is a more chance for others (even me) helping you?

Answer (score 1):

Are you allowed to implement the functions yourself?

```
def find_substring(string, substring):
    for i in range(len(string)-len(substring)+1):
        if string[i:i+len(substring)] == substring:
            return i
    return -1

def replace(string, substring, new):
    i = find_substring(string, substring)
    return string[:i] + new + string[i+len(substring):]
```

Comment: Yes, we're allowed to do that. I tried it out but it ended up replacing "AWAY FROM KEYBOARD" with just "AFK FROM KEYBOARD"

Comment: sry there was a small mistake. i fixed it

Comment: It works like a charm. :) I was just wondering, I have to replace "AWAY FROM KEYBOARD" with "AFK", but I also have to do a few more. For the other ones, do I just write a new def replace(string, substring, new): and just replace the substring and new?

Comment: no you can call a function as often as you want. `new_string = replace(the_original_string, the_string_you_want_to_replace, the_string_you_want_it_to_replace_with)`

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about that. Thank you, I'm going to try implementing it fully in and see how that goes :)

Comment: It should be allowed like this because you don’t use the builtin find-function. But if you want you can just rename the function ;)

Comment: No problem!.  ;)